# Open source loan amortization schedule

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I suppose this is a follow-up to [this previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962057/are-there-any-bsd-or-lgpl-libraries-for-calculating-amortization-schedules), but I have been searching for an open-source library that is usable with Objective-C that will take loan parameters and generate an amortization schedule.  I know there are tons of iPhone apps out there that generate amortization schedules, but what libraries do they use?

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they don't use existing libraries. Maybe they just calculate amortization scheduled based on formulas that can be easily implemented in C/C++/Objective-C.

Comment: Bingo. It's [not that complex a formula](http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/amortization-calculation.html). A library would be a waste of time.

Comment: Actually it can be very complex.  There are many types of loans, for example:  calculation method (360/365, 365/365), payment frequency (monthly, weekly, bi-weekly), calculating the effects of additional payments, escrow amounts (if any), etc.

Comment: I agree with Bill Shiff. It's not hard in theory when the borrower pays the same amount every month on the same day. But in the real world the day the payment occurs can vary and so can amount paid. In addition for large amounts using built-in types like floats and doubles become inaccurate. At least optimization is easy, pay the amount with the highest interest first.